# Does ANT support Maps(Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, ant

I am trying to using javascript within ant, by inlining it. However whenever I run the build, it reads

```
<eval>:15 ReferenceError: "Map" is not defined
```

I have the bsf jar, js.jar in the lib folder of ant. Since maps where introduced in ES6, I would like to know if there is some specific jar I need to include for it to work.

Comment: Might help if you can make a small build file that shows the problem and post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Ant Script Task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html), it uses Rhino which [supports JavaScript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Overview) which is way before ES6.